# I'm Making Volcano Eruption and the Splatter Texture Always Repeats, Why?

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, uv, node-editor

I'm trying to make a volcano eruption modeling like in CG Geek Youtube Channel. The guy who teaches in CG Geek is using 2.79 but I'm using 2.8 and I'm doing exactly the same things with the guy but
when I want to this result:[image: One texture is for rocks and another texture is for lava]

I'm getting this wrong result.

While my rocks texture works well, my lava texture is repeating 
like that: 
[image: Repeating Lava]

I don't understand what am I doing wrong??

Here is the CG Geek Node Editor:
[image: Left half of node editor]
[image: Right half of node editor]

And my shape editor:
[image]

I used two UV map like him also, but I don't know what is the problem. Is that about shape editor?
Thanks for your advice and helps.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Using all caps is considered rude

Comment: Do you even have a UV map connected to the vector input of any of your texture nodes?

Comment: Yes, I have but I solved that problem. I think I needed to add an attribute for the texture that repeats. I added an attribute and named it with the first UV Map which has the correct shape. And it ok now. Thank you for your interest my friend @Sazerac